# What is filter automation?

Tags: software, synthesizer, effects

I know what the effect of a filter on the sound of a synthesizer is, but I don't get wat the difference is between using a filter and filter automation.

Comment: Could this not have been answered with a simple google search?

Comment: when i google for the difference between these two, I can only find pages about the excel filter function. But maybe, you can help me out :)

Comment: Then it is a good question. ;-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Automation* is a feature available in most digital audio workstations and many types of similar audio production software. Automation allows a parameter like volume, pan, or mute to be changed automatically during playback of a song by the software.

In the early years of multi-track mixing, engineers had to manually move faders, and turn knobs while recording the mixdown if they wanted to make changes during the mix. Sometimes the whole band, producer, and assistant engineer would help move faders during the mixdown because there were so many tracks and so many changes that were desired.

In the mid 70's, console makers started building consoles that could change the levels automatically using voltage controlled amplifiers (the same technology used for envelope generators in synthesizers). Now with digital mixing almost anything can be automated, including settings that are part of third-party plug-ins, like a synthesizer plugin.

So filter automation is the automation of one or more filter settings. The most popular setting to automate for a synth filter is certainly the cutoff frequency. That one setting is so popular for automation that the phrase "filter automation" really refers to "filter cutoff frequency automation".

When you set up the filter on a synth, you choose a single filter setting, including the cutoff frequency, and you leave it there (assuming you don't use an envelope). With automation, you can make the filter open and close during the song, which is a very popular sound.

Skip to 4:20 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrtBp7AUHXE) to see how automation is done (in Logic Pro 9) and how it sounds.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I really understand what automation means!
I posted this question, because I didn't know what was happening in the last track of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-_7LUSYGtk) at 0:45.
Actually I still don't know which parameter is automated there... A cut-off frequency between 50 and 140 Hz, seems very strange. Can you help me once again? :)